# ConstraintLayout not wrapping content nor matching parent

Tags: android, scrollview, android-constraintlayout

Below you can see my XML code where I have a `ConstraintLayout` in a `ScrollView`. The ConstraintLayout does not wrapping content and i cant find the problem. It actually "hides" some of my views - in this case a button.
When I try to change the height attribute in the `ConstraintLayout` nothing happens so i feel its something else that i cant find.
Thank you

[image: This is what i get]

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#546E7A"
tools:context="com.example.android.business_card.MainActivity">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainConst"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logotop" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing2"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/map2"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing"
        android:text="@string/map"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing2"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/phone3"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing"
        android:text="@string/phone"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="19dp"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing2"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/web2"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing"
        android:text="@string/site"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/spacing"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spacing2"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/spacing2"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/spacing"
        android:background="@color/butCol"
        android:text="@string/sign"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved - i had to use android:fillViewport="true" in the scrollview attributes.